# Annotation of @[object] for NSArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode4.5, xcode4.4

I happend to see one particular code,

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

What's the name of annotation `@[indexPath]`, I never see this kind. and since when it introduces in objective-C. I know it replaces `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath,nil]`, any other functions of that? what the feature to use this (well, other than shorter)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an extension to the "Literals" available in Objective-C with LLVM. I don't believe it does anything else apart from create an array. They became available with Apple LLVM 4.0.

If you'd like to see all the literals available, check out http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html - they're quite handy.

Answer (score 1):

It is new way to use literals in Xcode 4.4
No other benefit I guess but its new style of coding

Few references are as, I hope this will clear few of your doubts.

```
int a = 2;
int b = 5;
NSNumber *n = @(a*b);
```

`@blah` is called the "literal" syntax. You use it to make objects wrapping a literal, like a char, BOOL, int, etc. that means:

- `@42` is a boxed int
- `@'c'` is a boxed char
- `@"foo"` is a boxed char*
- `@42ull` is a boxed unsigned long long
- `@YES` is a boxed BOOL

All of the things following the at sign are primitive values. `MyEnumValue` is not a literal. It's a symbol. To accommodate this, generic boxing syntax was introduced:

`@(MyEnumValue)`

You can put a bunch of things inside the parentheses; for the most part, any sort of variable or expression ought to work.

Comment: Literals were introduced in [Xcode 4.4](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_4.html).

Comment: +1 for the answer. And it was introduced in 4.4 as mentioned above.

Comment: Object literals may be faster and are certainly less error-prone. The big advantage is that `arrayWithObjects:` and similar methods require a `nil` at the end to tell them where the list ends; with a literal, you do not end the list with `nil`, so that's one fewer thing to forget.